# Picking global scope over local

Tags: javascript

I wonder, If is it any way in Javascript to tell compiler from which scope variable you wanna use.

Like in python appending keyword `global` and compiler knows that you're using global one.

Is it any way to do same in Javascript, beside using a different name?

*(In the sample below I'm trying to reach out for global "red", but it's been shadowing with argument "green".)*

```js
const color = "red"

const printColor = (color) => console.log(color)

printColor("green")
```

Comment: No, there isn't. Just use different names if you don't want to conflict.

Comment: Lets be evil: `const e = c => eval(c); const color = "red"; const printColor = color => console.log(e("color")); printColor("green");` but seriously, don't do this.

Comment: To be fair, you cannot undo the shadowing of a variable. The example where `color` is a parameter cannot be made to work as global in Python either, unless you remove it as parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Attach the global var directly to the window object:

```js
window.color = "red"

const printColor = (color) => console.log(color, window.color)

printColor("green")
```

### Update

Alternatively, you could create a "global" object and keep all your global vars in it:

```js
const global = {
    color: "red"
}

const printColor = (color) => console.log(color, global.color)

printColor("green")
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @symlink 's answer, but just as an additional bit of information.

A way to do this would be to bind the `context` of the appropriate `this` to the function.

For instance, because `var` will hoist variables ( *outside of strict mode* ) to `window`, you could potentially do something like the following:

```js
var color = "blue";

const printColor = function() { 
console.log(this.color) 
}

printColor.bind( window )()
printColor.bind({ color: "green" })()
```

We could also shorthand this to simply accept the `scope` as the argument.

```js
var color = "blue";

const printColor = scope => console.log(scope.color)


printColor(window);
printColor({color: "green"})
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparison with Python should be done in a fair way.

When in Python you have:

```py
x = 1 # global
def test(x):
    print(x)
```

... you cannot insert the `global` keyword to let that `print(x)` act on the global `x`, as you already defined that name as a local name (a parameter).

To continue for a moment in the Python world. This will act on the global variable:

```py
x = 1
def test():
    print(x) # global
```

...but as soon as you have an assignment, the variable will be considered to be local:

```py
x = 1
def test():
    x = 2 # local
    print(x)
```

To override this behaviour, you use `global`:

```py
x = 1
def test():
    global x
    x = 2 # global
    print(x)
```

Now, back to JavaScript. Here you can play with the word `var`.

To use the variable within the function, you just omit defining it with `let`, `const` or `var` in there:

```
var x = 1;

function test() {
    console.log(x); // global
}
```

To use the variable as local variable, then *do* use `var`, `let` or `const`:

```
var x = 1;

function test() {
    var x = 2; // local
    console.log(x);
}
```

So it is not that different. When in Python you use the `global` keyword, you don't use `var`, `let` or `const` in JavaScript, and where you omit Python's `global`, you *do* use `var`, `let` or `const` in JavaScript.

#### `globals()` versus `globalThis`

Python has `globals()` with which you *can* reference a global variable when you also have a local variable with the same name:

```py
x = 1

def test(x = 2):
    globals()['x'] = 3 # modifies the global variable
```

In JavaScript you would be able to do this via the global object, which is `window` in a browser context. See also the newer [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis). So in a browser context you *can* do this (but it needs `var`):

```
var x = 1;

function test(x = 2) {
    window.x = 3 // modifies the global variable
}
```

It would be better practice though, to just define your global variable as part of an object:

```
var myglobals = { x: 1 };

function test(x = 2) {
    myglobals.x = 3 // mutates myglobals
}
```